# Grails show action of superclass is not being called

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

I extended grails RestfulController to provide my own implementation. But If I call the url /api/loc/1 it will not call the super class show method. Meanwhile If I put the show method in the subclass It is being called. Here is my subclass:

```
 class MYRestfulController <T> extends RestfulController<T> {
   def show() {
        log.debug("inside show")
        //Other code
    }
    }
```

Now the controller:

```
class LocationController extends MYRestfulController<Location>{
}
```

Other methods are working as expected. Any Ideas?

Comment: What is called then? 404? Are you using scaffolding? Maybe scaffolded method is injected to your subclassed controller?

Comment: No I'm not using scaffolding

Comment: RestfulController already have method show() http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/rest/RestfulController.html#show() maybe that is causing problem?

Comment: What other methods you're testing out and claim they work as expected? Is any method that works also defined in `RestfulController`? What is the error message you get while calling this method?

Comment: index() method works as expected. The error I got is Http 404

Comment: This works if I override show method in controller. Any Idea why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't extended RestfullController, but with Grails 2.3.11 while extending restless controllers, I've always had to redeclare actions and call the super classes in them.

```
def create(params) { super.create(params);return }
def save(params) { super.save(params);return }
def show(Long id, Long formId, params) { super.show(id,formId,params);return }
def edit(Long id, params) { super.edit(id,params);return }
def update(Long id, Long version, params) { super.update(id,version, params);return }
```